# Convert any local time to GMT time using provided offset

Tags: datetime, xslt

Using XSLT 1.0 I need to convert a date-time value into GMT.

1. Input is an XML file which contains a date-time field with value of the format "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss+mm:ss".
2. I am not sure of the timezone this time is taken from.
3. So currently I add/subtract the offset with this time to deduce the GMT time.

**Example:**

> Time in input XML = *2015-06-16T15:00:31+02:00*
>
> Offset = *+02:00*
>
> Therefore, GMT Time = *[Time in input XML] - [Offset]*  = *15:00:31 - 02:00* = ***13:00:31***

Will the offset present in the XML time change according to daylight savings?

Answer (score 0):

> Will the offset present in the XML time change according to daylight
>   savings?

Yes. Or at least it should, if it follows the standard.

Comment: I am not sure what is the standard followed to represent the time.

The XML file is sent to us from a upstream Java Application and by looking at the samples I assume the format used is ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.

Any idea if this format follows the standard which changes the offset while representing the time during daylight savings?

Comment: Yes. The ISO 8601 standard refers to "local time", which changes as daylight savings goes into or out of effect. The Java class follows this standard: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME

Answer (score 0):

> Will the offset present in the XML time change according to daylight savings?

It depends what you mean. If the offset is +02:00, that means 2 hours after UTC. UTC isn't affected by daylight savings, and so a dateTime with an offset of +02:00 isn't affected by daylight savings either. In winter, it will correspond to the time shown by clocks in Kiev, in summer, it won't.